# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component: using useState in function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

everyone. I'm new to React and JavaScript.

Now I'm working on a web application.
I'm trying to solve this error for one week and I'm totally lost..
If anyone has any advice, help me, please.

When the program calls "useFetchTechData" function, it got this error.

The program for useFetchTechData is below:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";


const useFetchTechData = (TechIndicator, StockSymbol, Interval, TimePeriod, PriceType, API_KEY) => {
    
    let Function_API_Call = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=${TechIndicator}&symbol=${StockSymbol}&interval=${Interval}&time_period=${TimePeriod}&series_type=${PriceType}&apikey=${API_KEY}`
    let technicalChartXValuesFunction = [];
    let technicalChartYValuesFunction = [];
    const [technicalChartXValues, setTechnicalChartXValues] = useState([]);
    const [technicalChartYValues, setTechnicalChartYValues] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(Function_API_Call)
        .then(
            function(response) {
                return response.json();
            }
        )
        .then(
            function(data) {
                for(var key in data['Technical Analysis: ' + TechIndicator]) {
                    technicalChartXValuesFunction.push(key);
                    technicalChartYValuesFunction.push(data['Technical Analysis: ' + TechIndicator][key][TechIndicator]);
                }
                
                setTechnicalChartXValues(technicalChartXValuesFunction);
                setTechnicalChartYValues(technicalChartYValuesFunction);
            }
        )
    }, [Function_API_Call]);
    
    console.log(technicalChartXValues, technicalChartYValues)
    return { technicalChartXValues, technicalChartYValues };
}
 
export default useFetchTechData;
```

The code when calls useFetchTechData is below:

```
const useTechnicalClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsPending(true);
    setAfterInit(true);
    let technicalData = useFetchTechData(TechIndicator, StockSymbol, Interval, TimePeriod, PriceType, API_KEY);
    technicalChartXValues = technicalData[0];
    technicalChartYValues = technicalData[1];
}
```

Error is below:
[image]

Comment: How/Where is `useTechnicalClick` used?

Comment: `useTechnicalClick` looks like an event callback handler. You can't use React hooks in callbacks. See [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). You need to move `useTechnicalClick ` into the function body of the component using it. You should probably also rename it so it isn't named like a React hook, i.e. sans the "use"-prefix. If you need more help then you should update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of all relevant code related to issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. 
It seems like the comment from Drew Reese is pretty much what I should do to make it work. Thank you again for reading my messy code and giving good advice.